# google-services.json is missing when added google services.json

Tags: android, firebase

[Added google services.json in my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njtoe.png)

any one can help me,please
I don't find any solution.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider adding output log of your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space that is in the filename before the dot:

`google-services .json`